specifying multiple mail formats in a monit file
I have a very long monit file, with different rules.
For certain rules, I want to send an email (with a specific format) to multiple email addresses.
I thought about using a Message Format, but we have different mail formats in the file, so I don't think this will work.
Currently, the only "solution" that we have is to repeat the following block for each alert:
check 1
 alert email1@domain.com with mail-format {
  <FORMAT 1>
 }
 alert email2@domain.com with mail-format {
  <FORMAT 1>
 }

check 2
 alert email1@domain.com with mail-format {
  <FORMAT 2>
 }
 alert email2@domain.com with mail-format {
  <FORMAT 2>
 }

Do you know how we could extract that mail format so we don't have to copy it over and over again ?

You can use M/Monit to define the additional mail handling, but Monit can not.

@lutzmad Any idea how it can be done with M/Monit ? I cannot find that in their documentation.

You can define multiple "Send mail to address" for an alert in "Alerts" and "Rules" in the "Admin" menue, Lutz

Your are right, only one "set mail-format {}" statement is available to define the default mail format. Feel free to add a feature request via https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues.
